# AngularJS how to re-initialize directive?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, directive

I have a directive in AngularJS which is first initialized by default when the parent controller of it is being loaded.

The directive takes data from remote server using AJAX and implements the data in checkboxes - each checkbox get the clue if its already checked or not.

On first load of this page (controller) and directive, the checkboxes are being checked properly.

When I move to another scope (controller) and then back again to the checkboxes scope, none of them are checked.
Even though the data is being requested again from the remote server using AJAX (I console logged it), those checkboxes are ain't get checked.

Should I re-init the directive?

This is the directive (notice the checked attribute):

```
<checkbox key="{{num}}" selector="{{category.key}}/{{module.key}}" changefunction="togglePermission"
              checked="{{permissions[num] && permissions[num].modules.indexOf(category.key+'/'+module.key)!=-1}}"></checkbox>
```

and this is the checkbox directive html file:

```
<div class="form-group" ng-class="{'has-danger': errors[selector].length>0}">
  <label class="control control-outline control--checkbox {{selector}}">
    <div class="input-group">
      <span ng-show="title.length>0">{{title}}</span>
      <input type="checkbox"
      ng-model="this[key][selector]"
      ng-disabled="loading"
      ng-click="this[changefunction](key, selector)"
      ng-checked="checked"
      />
      <span class="control__indicator"></span>
    </div>
  </label>
  <small class="text-danger" ng-show="errors[selector].length>0">{{errors[selector]}}</small>
</div>
```

A quick explaination: I am sending custom key and selector names, for example:

```
$scope.teams = {
  level: ""
}
```

So the `teams` will be the key and the `level` will be the selector

This is the checkbox component js file:

```
app.directive("checkbox", ($rootScope, parseService) => {
  return {
    templateUrl: "/shared/checkbox/checkbox.html",
    scope: true,
    link: function($scope, element, attrs) {

       $scope.key = parseService.parse(attrs.key);
       $scope.selector = parseService.parse(attrs.selector);
       $scope.changefunction = parseService.parse(attrs.changefunction);
       $scope.checked = parseService.parse(attrs.checked);

    }
  }
});
```

Comment: Can you post all your code in a [JSFiddle](http://www.jsfiddle.net)?

Comment: I am not sure if it works since there middlewares of accessing this data - requiring access token and some other root configurations.

Comment: I think that the problem is not in AngularJS. I think its in the bootstrap css class which is append or removed via jquery.

Comment: Without a working fiddle it will be almost impossible to debug.  You would need to post some small example of the problem, perhaps simulating the ajax calls with hardcoded data.